# replace specific column values using reference of another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

i have shell script and a piece of code has to create a file by replacing column1 values of File1 and filling values from File2.

```
$ cat File1
CUST01,375
CUST02,379
```

and:

```
$ cat File2
CUST01,CUST01,233901
CUST01,CUST01,233902
```

required output from File2:

```
375,CUST01,233901 
375,CUST01,233902
```

i have tried below command to fill values from File1 to File2,

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next } { for(i in a) {for(x=1;x<=NF;x++) {$x=(i==$x)?a[i]:$x } } }1' File1 File2`
```

and getting below output

```
375,375,233901
375,375,233902
```

i want to replace corresponding values in column1 only, instead awk method results replacing values in all columns, any help.

Comment: Your "required output" and the output you are getting look the same to me.

Comment: sorry,, its due to auto corrections..  my expected output is to replace values in column1 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, but its without error checking:

```
declare -A dict
while IFS=, read -r key value; do
    dict[$key]="$value"
done < file1

while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3; do
    printf "%s,%s,%s\n" "${dict[$col1]}" "$col2" "$col3"
done < file2
```

**explanation**

```
# create associativ array
declare -A dict

# read key and value from file, separator is ','
while IFS=, read -r key value; do
    # write key and value into associativ array
    dict[$key]="$value"
done < file1

# loop over file2, read three columns, separator is ','
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3; do
    # print columns, first column is the value from associativ array
    printf "%s,%s,%s\n" "${dict[$col1]}" "$col2" "$col3"
done < file2
```

Comment: Thanks UtLox.. it works and MANY MANY thanks for giving explanation of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not an `awk` expert, but this seems to work for me:

```
awk -v FS=',' -v OFS=',' 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2; next } { $1 = a[$2] }1' File1 File2
```

With your example input files, this is the output:

```
375,CUST01,233901
375,CUST01,233902
```

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks.. it works for my above input files, but if my File2 has CUST02 and output should display corresponding value from FIle1 (379), that's not working.

Comment: @SSK it works fine. Added a `CUST02` to `File2` and re-tested and it works correctly. You may have copy/pasted wrong.